# Error: Parse Error - Invalid header value char in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tls1.2, response-headers

I'm encountering a "Parse Error: Invalid header value char" in my Node.js application. The error stack trace points to an issue in the TLSSocket.socketOnData function. I've checked my code, but I'm unable to pinpoint the cause. Here's a brief overview of my setup:

- Using Express.js
- MongoDB connection with Mongoose

The error occurs intermittently, and I suspect it might be related to the payload or headers. I've already tried the axios instance but it also same on Postman.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error: Parse Error: Invalid header value char\n    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:534:22)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)\n    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)\n    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)\n    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

Comment: Is the served data UTF8 encoded? Are you returning the same data every time when you get the intermittent issue? Maybe try hard coding a response rather than reaching out to mongo and then you can isolate the issue to either the backend code or the returned data from Mongo.

Comment: It is not UTF8, I will try to hard code the response. Thank you.

Comment: I saw UTF8, but not sure if this is the served data, @JacquesRamsden

Comment: Error: Parse Error: Invalid header value char
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:534:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  bytesParsed: 328,
  code: 'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN',
  reason: 'Invalid header value char',
  rawPacket: Buffer(1020) [Uint8Array]